# Question about javascript xmlhttp and there response

Tags: php, javascript, curl, xmlhttprequest

as a fix to a previous problem of mine, i have thought to run a cURL script using JavaScript to prevent my site waiting for a response of each one.

at the moment I have this script given by a friend and i have noticed something.

[Link to JS file](http://www.nygate.mainwebs.com/send.js)

My question is if I were to remove the following lines, would it mean that the page would not wait for a response?

```
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        setTimeout("location.reload(true)",1500);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you pop that in notepad, indent it, and bring it back? That's really hard to read.

Comment: i was reading your script and noticed that its double spaced, then i stopped reading it

Comment: @DampeS8N one thing I miss in Chrome is the Firefox "It's All Text!" plugin, which is really fantastic for exactly this kind of situation :-)

Comment: ok instead of just C&Ping it there i have posted a hyperlink to the file it self, enjoy having a read :D

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the lines, it will not go anywhere.

If you want to speed it up, get rid of the setTimeout line, that is not nessecary.

If you were to remove the if statement, and just do the window.locaiton line, it will fire before the request is made since that onreadystatechange fires to tell you when the request is opened, started, transferring, and done.

[Ajax 101 Article](http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/xmlhttpreq.html)

Comment: just as a question if i remove the window.location time and removed the if statement would it be okay?

Comment: So your onreadystatechange event would look like `onreadystatechange = function(){}`?